# How to inject OSGi service to EJB with Blueprint

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I know it is possible to use [ServiceTracker](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html) to inject OSGi services to EJBs.

However, how should I use [OSGi Blueprint XML configuration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-osgiblueprint/) to inject services to standard EJBs, so that services would be available when EJBs are used elsewhere?
Or is it really impossible, as EJBs work in a layer of their own?

I've been trying to do this with Aries Blueprint as well as Gemini Blueprint, with JBoss AS7, without luck.

As an example bean:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class SimpleStatelessSessionBean {

  InformationService service; // how'd I go about to get this populated?

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {

  }

  public String getMessage() {

    if (service == null)
      throw new IllegalStateException("Service not available");

    return "EJB:" + service.getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: [PAX CDI](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI) is intended specifically to solve this problem. You should look into it.

Comment: @BjörnPollex it says on http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Web+Applications that "Pax CDI only works with the traditional Pax Web Jetty container. It does not yet support the Pax Web Tomcat container." - I don't think it's an alternative to other containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what I asked is not really possible.

What is possible is

- for spring apps, use [Gemini Blueprint](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/) which combines spring injection with OSGi
- for ejbs/servlets, use CDI/OSGi integration component. There exists [PAX CDI](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI) for Pax Web and [JBoss Weld OSGi integration](http://mathieuancelin.github.com/weld-osgi/html/index.html) ([somewhat usable now](https://Fwww.jboss.org/dms/judcon/presentations/London2011/day2session4.pdf), [in process for JBoss AS](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-6073)), at least
- for any app, when else fails, programmatic usage of ServiceTracker works